# Limit of function as derivative

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, limits-without-lhopital

I want to calculate $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}\left(\frac{f(x)}{f(a)}\right)^{\frac{1}{\ln{x}-\ln{a}}}$, where $f$ is a differentiable function  at $x=a$ with $f(a)>0$.

I found this exercises in some calculus notes in the section of derivatives, so I guess the objective of the exercise is to write the expression as the limit definition of derivatives. My guess is there is a typo, because if the fraction of the exponent is $\frac{1}{x-a}$ instead it's direct writing the expression as $\exp(\ln(g(x))$ with $g$ the function in the limit.

Even if there is a typo I would like to know how to calculate this limit. My tries has been writing that expression as $\exp(\ln(g(x))$, aply continuity of exponential and use logarithm properties, but I haven't got anything useful.

Also, I would appreciate answers without L'hopital as this exercise is at the start of the section of derivatives of the notes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the exponent, my immediate instinct is to take the logarithm. If
$$
L :=\lim_{x\to a}\left(\frac{f(x)}{f(a)}\right)^{\frac{1}{\ln{x}-\ln{a}}}
$$
then by continuity and logarithm properties,
$$
\ln(L)= \lim_{x \to a} \frac{\ln(f(x)) - \ln(f(a))}{\ln(x)-\ln(a)}
$$
One may note that
$$
\frac{\ln(f(x)) - \ln(f(a))}{\ln(x)-\ln(a)}
= \frac{\ln(f(x)) - \ln(f(a))}{x-a} \cdot \frac{x-a}{\ln(x)-\ln(a)}
$$
and use the definition of derivative and solve for $L$ to conclude.

Comment: I feel so dumb, just a convenient 1 away, thanks!

Comment: lol, happens to the best of us. I only recognized it so immediately because I'm used to this kind of trick. Pops up a lot.